# ActiveRecord query ordering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seat
  ...
end

class Seat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :color
  ...
end 

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :name
  ...
end
```

If I have get a list of Cars, and I want to **order the Cars by color.name**, how to write the order query?

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :seat
   ...
   def cars_order_by_color(car_ids)
       where(:id=>car_ids).order(?????) #HOW TO ORDER BY COLOR.name
   end   

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `joins` on your query, you can then sort by the joined tables (either `seats` or `colors`):

```
Car.joins(:seat => :color).order("colors.name")
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve records from the database in a specific order, you can specify the :order option to the find call.

```
 Car.order("color")
```

You could specify ASC or DESC as well:

```
 Car.order("color DESC")
```

For more help in query look here: [active_record_querying](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

You can use find_by_sql:

```
Car.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM clients
  INNER JOIN orders ON clients.id = orders.client_id
  ORDER clients.created_at desc")
```

Write appropriate query.

Comment: Hi, Harry Joy, thanks for your reply, but your answer is not what I expected, I know how to order. If you check my models carefully, my question is about ordering by associated model objects. I would like to order Cars by Color, where "Color" is a model associated with "Seat", and "Seat" is a model associated with "Car". That's I want to order cars by color.name, this kind of order, I am not sure how to implement.